# mysql only max of count with several max

Tags: mysql, database, join, count, max

I am looking for a query, getting only the biggest one's.

```
SELECT results.playerid, 
       username, 
       Count(*) AS count 
FROM   results 
       LEFT JOIN players 
              ON results.playerid = players.playerid 
WHERE  points = 5 
GROUP  BY playerid 
ORDER  BY count DESC
```

Result:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------+
| playerID  | username  | count |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
| 1         | Lorem     | 2     |
| 2         | Ipsum     | 2     |
| 3         | Dolor     | 1     |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------+
| playerID  | username  | count |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
| 1         | Lorem     | 2     |
| 2         | Ipsum     | 2     |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

Would be no problem if there would be only one biggest.

Any tips?

**Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c74c17/1**

Comment: Show us current and expected output. In case of ties what you want to return?

Comment: btw not related to your question. but you should change `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(players.playerID)` otherrwise you wont get result 0 when left join doesnt found a match.

Comment: thx. added the expected output.

Comment: what version of mysql you have?

Comment: 5.6.36-82.0-log

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you need to find out what is the max value for the `group by`

```
SELECT Count(players.playerid) AS count 
FROM   results 
       LEFT JOIN players 
              ON results.playerid = players.playerid 
WHERE  points = 5
GROUP  BY players.playerid
ORDER  BY count DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Then you use that query to filter the result you need.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c74c17/7)**

```
SELECT results.playerid, 
       username, 
       Count(players.playerid ) AS count 
FROM   results 
       LEFT JOIN players 
              ON results.playerid = players.playerid 
WHERE  points = 5 
GROUP  BY playerid 
HAVING COUNT(players.playerid) = (
          SELECT Count(players.playerid) AS count 
          FROM   results 
                 LEFT JOIN players 
                        ON results.playerid = players.playerid 
          WHERE  points = 5
          GROUP  BY players.playerid
          ORDER  BY count DESC
          LIMIT 1
);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| playerid | username | count |
|----------|----------|-------|
|        1 |    Lorem |     2 |
|        2 |    Ipsum |     2 |
```